# Hide DataList row based on value from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am retrieving a set of value from a web service and populating a dataList with those values-

```
ActiveDataList.DataSource = ws.TermsReturnActive(sql);
ActiveDataList.DataBind();
```

How can I hide a particular column of the dataList depending on the value, 
e.g.

```
if(value == 1)
{ 
 //Hide Column 
}
```

This action however would have to hide the same row of another dataList in parallel to it.
I can modify a cell on this second dataList using by retrieving the value from the first as so -

```
TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)sender;
        DataListItem item1 = (DataListItem)tb1.NamingContainer;

        TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)tData.Items[item1.ItemIndex].FindControl("tTextBox");

        string term = txt1.Text;
```

So if I can retrieve a value from a separate dataList row, I was thinking I would also be able to adjust its visability.

How can I achieve this as the web service call is done in the page load so I believe it would have to be done when the dataList item is bound?

Answer (score 1):

if iam right, you should have something like this in your aspx-file right?:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound"></asp:DataList>
```

As you can see you should add a "OnItemDataBound" Event where you can check your value and hide a item, if you want.

So you can react like this and hide some items:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
       {
           TextBox tbCurrentTextBox = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tTextBox");
           if (DataList1.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString() == "1")
           {
               e.Item.Visible = false;
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: this brings back - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index. I made sure I referenced the correct datalist plus control, what do you suggest?

Comment: have a look at my answer i added a check if the current item is a type of "item" so you wont get a error.